# Can't turn on Center Stage Studio Display

Tags: macos, display, camera, webcam

I have a brand new, 2022 16" MBP and a Studio Display. I can't turn on Center Stage.

The only option ever available to me in Video Effects is Portrait mode.  Any ideas how I get Center Stage here?

[image]

Comment: Does it work in Facetime?

Comment: Are you set to the Studio Display's camera? Macs don't have Centre Stage yet, it's leveraged into the Display cam.

Comment: Is that in Control Centre?  I see a switch for FaceTime and Zoom there, but not for Photo Booth. I suspect if Chrome doesn't support Centre Stage, then you can't use it. But  yeah, make sure you're using the Display's camera, not the MBP's.

Comment: [Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253817158) says it works in Chrome - so I can only guess the wrong camera is selected.

Comment: Yeah that's using the Studio Display + any app including FaceTime.